# LED light DROID 4

Tags: notification-led, motorola-droid-4

Can you change the color of the LED light on the DROID 4? Like is there an app or anything? If so, what's the name of the app, and how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Light Flow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rageconsulting.android.lightflow) to customize LED notifications; it also has a [lite version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rageconsulting.android.lightflowlite).

> Light Flow allows you to take control of your notification LED colors
>   and makes them successively flash one color after another.
>
> It also allows you to set repeating sounds on vibration patterns for
>   you notifications. You can also set a "sleep" mode or "on charge"
>   where the lights and/or sounds and vibrations will not be heard or
>   seen.